Humans with implants in body in the future
There was a movie I watched. I would bet it's older than 2010.
It's set in the future. People can have implants but it comes at the cost, I think of health. Particulary there was a priest who had a lot of these implants and was pretty much insane. I remember him going after the good guys and standing in front of their vehicle yelling "hold sinners" or sonething very similar.

This sounds like it could be a few things, but I'm going with my strongest feeling.  Hopefully my answer will at least attract some more eyes to the question.  If I mistook implants for being synonymous with artificial organs then I could be way off.

This sounds like Johnny Mnemonic from 1995, based on William Gibson's cyberpunk short story. It has:

Keanu Reeves as a cybernetic courier with a memory chip implanted in his head which is the main mcguffin driving the plot.
The data from the chip is leaking into his mind, affecting his memories.
Dolph Lundgren as a street preacher, quite insane. IMDB's Quotes page for the character lists this among them:


Street Preacher: HALT SINNERS! 


